# Looking for something like "tee" but which open/closes the target file with each write?

Tags: linux, shell, tee

I've got something like `mycommand | tee -a mylogfile.log` but because the log file resides on a disk which might be getting remounted over and over, I want to have `tee` open/close the file with each write (say, e.g. with each line). Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: you just need a separate script for this. however, why would you have your disk keep remounting?

Comment: One advantage of keeping the file open is that it will stop your system from remounting the disk (or, more precisely, from unmounting it — the device will be busy).

Comment: The reason for remount is that this is a VirtualBox shared drive, and I'm basically accounting for the possibility of the VM being suspended/resumed while my command is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will open and close `mylogfile.log` with each line:

```
mycommand | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s\n" "$line" | tee -a mylogfile.log; done
```

With bash, this can be slightly simplified:

```
mycommand | while IFS= read -r line; do tee -a mylogfile.log <<<"$line"; done
```

Comment: You could also simply do: `echo "$line"; echo "$line" >> mylogfile.log;` in the body of the loop, which means fewer executables are launched,etc.